# Eclipse Incremental Builder Plugin does not work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, builder, eclipse-pde

I recently started working with Eclipse's Plug-in development environment on Eclipse RCP (4.2.1 Juno). I created a project with the Incremental Builder Template. My goal is to perform a build process on the user code after Java Build is over. 
The problem is, I don't know how to use the Builder. I tried Exporting the project into a "Deployable Plug-ins and Fragments" jar file, and then placed the jar file in several places, like Development Workspace, Runtime Workspace, and in the plugins folder of the Development Eclipse.
I run the plugin project as an "Eclipse Application", a Runtime Eclipse comes up, I create a project, and define a builder for that project and give the exported jar as the builder file, and it's dir as the working dir and then Build the project and hope for the magic to happen!! But foolish me...
In all the cases, I get a Permission Denied message of the Form:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'A'.
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "<$Address>/Getter_1.0.0.201210200958.jar" (in directory "<$Address>"):     error=13, Permission denied
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "<$Address>Getter_1.0.0.201210200958.jar" (in directory "<Address>"): error=13, Permission denied
```

I think it has something to do with the location of my plugin, but I've tried everywhere, other than the plugins folder of the runtime eclipse, because I figured it's the same as the development eclipse... 
Any thoughts??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, the incremental builder example comes with a nature. So if you just crete the incremental builder example with next next finish, and you run it as an "eclipse application", then you should create a java project, right click on it, and choose "add .... nature". Then the builder will be enabled, and you will see if its working or not. So enable the nature.

You can check if the builder is enabled on the project with checking project properties. There is a builders section:

[image]

There is a complete tutorial for builders [here.](http://goo.gl/YMTJa)

Comment: I Love You!!! I just have one more Question. How can I deploy the project? Right now, my builder works fine on the Runtime Eclipse. But how can I deploy it to an Eclipse installation. I tried Exporting the project to a jar file and copying it to the plugins folder of several eclipses, but I couldn't get it to work!! Nothing in the menu as "Add Sample Nature"... Any thoughts?

Comment: Glad to hear, that everything is fine. Cool. Have a nice eclipse development. I have found it awesome, when i did it.