# Maven Incremental Plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, incremental-build

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am new to Maven , i had always use Ant.
I want to use the Incremental Build Plugin to reduce the application compilation and deploy time.
There is not much information related with this plugin. 
I have add the following code to the parent POM.

```
<plugin>
           <groupId>net.java.maven-incremental-build</groupId>
           <artifactId>incremental-build-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.6</version>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>incremental-build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But in the applications logs i verify that the target is deleted and the source folder is compiled every time.
What could am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: The plugin is a little bit out of date. Furthermore how long is your build time? Have you tried to use `mvn -T 3 ...` ? Which Maven version do you use? And what do you mean by deploy time? To a maven repository (I hope you are using a repository manager ? )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Incremental Builder Plugin does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987596/eclipse-incremental-builder-plugin-does-not-work)